# 8GB of ram working normally with 7.9 usable, then one day only 7.4 were usable, what happened?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, memory

I had a laptop with 4GB of ram, putted another 4GB for 8GB
the laptop was saying 7.9GB usable, pretty normal and expected. One day when I turned it on (4 to 6 months later), only 7.4 were usable. Did a chip burn or something? This is a lot of missing ram, so I reinstalled it, but still nothing changed.

EDIT: 560mb are hardware reserved (so the igpu?),
What happend? As I said, I did not updated any bios, didn't touched any settings
just the laptop itself reserved 600mb by nothing

Comment: "Did a chip burn or something?" - No;  Can you provide a screenshot of [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) for us?  Be sure you edit your question instead of submitting commentary.

Comment: Could be any number of things.  A driver update may have allocated RAM to an integrated graphics chip, or another driver allocated it. Is it causing an actual issue?

Comment: not sure, the thing is that i did not updated anything, bios, drivers, just one day i turned it on and 600mb were missing, i haven't touched the settings as well

Comment: Hmm, you forget to accept the answer :P

Comment: im sorry, but how do i do it? im new here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no RAM space is missing, there can only be one possibility: the space is reallocated/reserved.

Try to use Resource Monitor (`perfmon /res`), to open it:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→type `resmon`→<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then click Memory in the resultant window:

[image]

You can clearly see all RAM you have, you have installed 8GB RAM, so you will see 8192 MB installed. You say about 7.4 GB usable, so you will see about 7578 MB total, and there will be about 614 MB shown as "Hardware Reserved".

The RAM can't be missing, it can only be repurposed.

As for what did it, there are many possibilities, some driver or another, but most likely the culprit is your graphics card's driver, presumably Intel HD Graphics;

The settings changed are stored in your motherboard's firmware (BIOS), it is unclear what you mean by "so I reinstalled it", it can be either the Operating System (Windows), or the RAM module, but neither of them can take back the reserved RAM, as they don't change the BIOS.

To get back the reserved RAM, you need to get into BIOS, unfortunately this varies from motherboard to motherboard, so I can't help you much, you can search your motherboard's model online, and find better guides on how to boot into your motherboard's BIOS in Google. But most likely, the first screen you see when you start your computer, before Windows booted, is the welcome screen of BIOS, it will contain instructions on how to get into BIOS.

Then once you are in BIOS, you can shrink the RAM allocated to integrated graphics card, again this varies from motherboard to motherboard, again you can use Google to find the method. Though if you look for it hard enough in the BIOS settings, you will eventually find it.

But it is recommended against doing it, I actually allocated more RAM and processor speed to Intel HD Graphics 4600... WHY did I DO it? Am I stupid? No, it is because I am poor, and can't buy an NVIDIA dedicated graphics card, so there isn't dedicated GPU present in my computer.

Although there really are laptops with dedicated GPU, those are really expensive, and the cheap laptops most likely don't have dedicated GPUs. Chances are good if you aren't super rich, the laptops you bought don't have a dedicated graphics card. And it is impossible to put a dedicated GPU into a laptop that doesn't have one, it just can't fit; The best you can do, is to buy an external GPU and connect it to the laptop externally; eGPUs are a combination of a full-sized GPU, a PCIe slot and a desktop style Power Supply, refer to here to see [The Best Ways to Connect an External Graphics Card to Your Laptop](https://www.howtogeek.com/295442/the-best-ways-to-connect-an-external-graphics-card-to-your-laptop/#:%7E:text=An%20external%20GPU%20)

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Not exactly slim and mobile, huh?

Laptops are designed to be portable, mobile, they are designed to be small, so they can be carried anywhere, but by reducing the size of the laptop, you are also reducing the performance of the laptop, there are many physical constraints, sorry.

By adding an eGPU to the laptop, you can get a better experience when playing games, but the eGPU is so clunky it contradicts the purpose of laptops, making it a stupid thing to do, why not just buy a desktop computer if you have the money?

So my advise: just leave the reserved RAM be, if your laptop doesn't have a dedicated GPU and a slot for the GPU on motherboard, your integrated graphics card really needs it, and you in turn need your integrated graphics card if you want to do anything that outputs to the screen (which is practically everything)...

If you have dedicated GPU though, go ahead and free up the RAM.

---

You didn't change the settings, it is true, but that doesn't exclude the possibility of Windows doing it; Windows Update automatically detects, downloads and installs updates by default, Windows Update also installs drivers, presumably you didn't disable the `wuauserv` service, so it is very likely Windows Update installed the driver for Intel HD Graphics when you were not using your computer, and the driver reserved the "missing" RAM space.

Comment: Just a side note, laptops with dedicated GPUs also suffer from such allocation problems.

Comment: the laptop is HP 630 G1, yes it does not have slot for dedicated GPU
the laptop is with a HD 4600
my current one has a dedicated, i know how big they are
back to the ram... so you tell me that the GPU took 600mb of ram?
even i dont know what happend, i did not updated any bios, dribers, firmware, NOTHING!
and one day i turned it on and BOOB 600mb missing, i will check the reseourse monitor and see if they are there

Comment: @Valay_17 Wow, I am sorry I never knew there exist laptops with dedicated GPU, really? How can the GPU fit into the laptop? How can the GPU draw power? How can the GPU dissipate heat?

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Wdym, there are laptops with inbuilt dedicated GPUs, eg, Asus TUF A15 with RTX2060.

Comment: yes there are a lot laptops with dedicated gpus, mine is DELL and it does have dedicated
they are very power efficent!
and about the size, its giant

Comment: Yeah, just Googled it, there really are laptops with dedicated GPUs, but those are really expensive, fancy and cost-prohibitive, with less price, you can get a desktop with far better performance... Never the less, you can't put a GPU into a laptop that doesn't have a GPU...

Comment: @MartoxD Your two comments are contradictive to each other, the discrepancy makes it hard to determine whether or not the laptop in question has a GPU, if you do have a GPU, I will revise my answer to tell you how to free up the reserved RAM.

Comment: my old laptop (the HP) does not have dedicated,
my new one has (the DELL)

Comment: putting a external gpu in laptop is very hard, you need to buy a lot of thing and cut the the plastic of the laptop, or not putting it wicht will result overheating, and with a bad cpu, this is not gonna do much

Comment: That was exactly what I meant by mentioning it, I strongly recommend buying desktop computers. Don't buy laptops because laptops really are not cost-effective.

Comment: ye they suck for most things

Comment: so these 600mb are hardware reserved (by the igpu?)